# spring event listener condition access field from parent (prototype) bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, events, event-listener

i need an event listener, that has a condition bounded to a field of the parent bean. The bean is scoped as prototype & the field i want the listener to use in the condition is set via setter once a repeatedTasksExecutor instance is created:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class RepeatedTasksExecutor implements Runnable, ApplicationListener<CustomEvent> {


    String gameId;

    public String getGameId() {
        return gameId;
    }

    public void setGameId(String gameId) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
    }



    //here i want to access the gameId field, that is set globally once the RepeatedTasksExecutor instance is initialized
    @EventListener(condition = "@gameId == #event.gameId")
        public void handleReturnedEvent(CustomEvent event) {
            System.out.println("gameid: "+ event.getGameId());
        }
    }
```

From the documentation i have seen, that its possible to access a constant, but i can not use that, because in every instance the field has another value.

Any ideas here?